# Does flattening JSON reduces its read/write time in C language

Tags: c, json

Recently I joined new org and there I am seeing that, for every nested json object they are flattening it for efficiency purpose. I am just wondering does even really improves performance in terms of time required to read/write and memory usage. If yes, then how much?

Original JSON:

```
{
  key1: {
           key11:val11,
           key12:val12
        }
  key2: {
           key21:val21,
           key22:val22
        }
}
```

Flatten JSON:

```
{
  key1_key11:val11,
  key1_key12:val12,
  key2_key21:val21,
  key2_key22:val22
}
```

As per my understanding there should not be change in memory usage but I am not sure about time required in both cases.

Comment: Why would you assume same memory usage? Besides storing the key names, there are data structures used to build the tree structure. In your first sample you need 6 nodes  and in the second you only need 4 nodes.

Comment: JSON is just text. You'd have to peek into the parser implementation to tell - there is no obvious reason why one should be more efficient than the other. Unless they are doing like back in the 1980s, trying to save file space of text files by reducing the number of bytes typed...

Comment: The performance will depend on the implementation.   I doubt any difference would be significant in most cases.  You need to test your specific implementation in the intented platform. It is unanswerable as a general question.  Questions about your approach to bench-marking it or the results you obtain may be appropriate.

Comment: Reading/writing from the file will probably take longer in first sample as more nodes need to be created. Searching keys in memory might be faster or slower using one of the 2 variants. It would depend on your data. If you have tons of keys on same level you might be faster using nested objects. Without knowing your data and doing some benchmarking that cannot be determined.

Comment: I would not work for that org.

Comment: If this kind of trick makes a difference, then they have obviously made a design mistake: They should have used some other format than JSON.

Comment: Sorry, JSON requires keys to be formatted as string literals (between double quotes) and doesn't permit identifiers as you post in your question (only the three literals `false`, `true` and `null`).  Read [ECMA 404](https://ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-404_1st_edition_october_2013.pdf)  for authoritary information.  You also missed a `,` comma between `key1` labeled subobject and `key2`.

Comment: You should do performance tests on your specific use case, doing it both ways and comparing the results. There are too many things that affect the performance to be able to make a general statement. (For example, how often is the data transformed? How often is the data queried? How often is the data written?)

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends on how you process your data.  Basically JSON format allows for one pass interpretation allowing no trace back.  So reading/interpreting JSON format with a LALR parser will have no penalties, at least based on the complexity of the document.

Of course, a deep tree document will require more memory, but will be as efficient as a flattened document.

In case you are going to read very big documents in JSON format, you will, at some point, need to start processing the document as you are reading it  (you will not be able to hold the whole document in memory and you will have to process it sequentially).  Most probably the bottleneck will be in the processing you need to do to the input file, than on reading or parsing it.  Parsing JSON is a one pass problem, requiring a fixed amount of time per character (`O(n)`)

By the way, the format you have posted is not actually JSON.  JSON format specifications are defined in [ECMA-404](https://ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-404_1st_edition_october_2013.pdf) and it only accepts `false`, `true` and `null` as the only unquoted identifiers.  You need to quote your keys with `"` characters (and the values you have used too).  A strict JSON parser (and I recommend you one to avoid misinterpretations) will reject both documents you posted.

On other side, flattening (you can simply count) will make your file bigger, and so you can end with a very big file, in which you will have to do a lot of processing if you want to recover the original document structure.  (in your document you use 28 characters for the keys, while you use 40 for the flattened keys, this will increment the reading time --I said above the reading time to be O(n)-- and also you will have to process the keys to recover the structure of the deep document) IMHO flattening will be a bad decision, as JSON standar was issued to allow structured documents to be exchanged (you break the structure thinking that parsing will be a non-scalable problem)

Answer (score 0):

In an ideal implementation, there should be no unnecessary reading.
Cause you gain each time you don't read a unnecessary input.
In top of that you also have smaller file.
But it can also waste time if you remove important syntax elements for parsing.

To reply to you question :
There are many ways to implement JSON parsing.
And the performance for memory and time depend mainly of the implementation you use to pars the JSON file.